# iOS Autolayout font adjustment with device size (iPhone 6 plus, iPhone 6, iPhone 5)

Tags: ios, ios8, size-classes, ios-autolayout

I am using autolayout and setting font in UILabel, or UITextField in wAny hAny size class.

Font looks good in iPhone 6 plus but on iPhone 5 its size does not change.

If we take example of UILabel, I set horizontal center and verticle center without giving width and Height.

How to make its font responsive with particular device size of iPhone.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 solutions:

1. Instead of setting the a vertical center constraint, set a leading and a tailing constraints. Set your text alignment to center.
   Then set the label's autoshrink property to "Minimum font scale/size" and you are good to go.
2. Use size classes on your font (by clicking the tiny "+" near your font name).
   This won't work with custom fonts because of an Xcode 6/7 bug (Apple is aware of this).

Comment: Thanks for comment. Solution 2 will not work in my case as i am using same size class for iPhone 6 plus, 6, 5. I am not using iPad. As far as setting leading, trailing constraint this seems to be solution but with dynamic content i think it will create problem